# What happens if I ReleaseMutex() twice?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mutex

The Microsoft documentation is silent about what happens if I mistakenly call `ReleaseMutex()`  when the mutex is already unlocked.

**Details:**

I'm trying to fix up some Windows code without having access to the compiler.

I realise that WinApi mutexes are all recursive, and reference-counted. If I were making use of that feature, it's obvious that the extra `ReleaseMutex()` call would prematurely decrement the reference counter.

However, the code that I am looking at does not use the mutex recursively, so the reference count never gets higher than '1'. It **does** release the mutex more times than necessary... so what happens? Does the reference count go negative? Does it stay at zero (unlocked) and just return an ignorable error?

(Naturally, this code doesn't actually check for errors when it calls these functions!)

Comment: This is a really bad question. Even if I would know, 'it checks under WinXP' it could be completely different under Win7. So you should really never do this. (NB: I think it is checked)

Comment: The documentation is not silent:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685066%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: peejaybee, you should upgrade that comment to an answer!

Comment: The Microsoft documentation page linked to above seems pretty clear:  if you call ReleaseMutex() on a mutex without having first acquired the mutex, the call will fail without any side effects.

That said, it would probably be wise not to rely on that behavior; instead you should make sure that your code always matches its mutex-releases with its mutex-acquisitions.

It's also rather poor form to insult the people who are trying to help you, for free, on their own time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[peejay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116853/peejaybee) provided a good link in his comment to the [ReleaseMutex documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685066%28VS.85%29.aspx). I believe that this line from the documentation answers your question:

> The ReleaseMutex function fails if the
>   calling thread does not own the mutex
>   object.

While it is not explicitly said, I think that releasing a mutex (the first time) causes the calling thread to no longer own the mutex object. Thus the second call will simply fail. Such an implementation would make sense too since it would allow easily detecting this type of error (Just check the return value).

Comment: "If the function fails, the return value is zero."

Comment: Here's the full quote: "If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError." So, having called GetLastError(), how can I distinguish this error condition from other errors that may occur?

Comment: @alex: `GetLastError()` will return a different value for the different error conditions... You can even use `FormatMessage` to create a human readable message from the error code.

Comment: So is it safe to call ReleaseMutex() twice? I abort my process instead of waiting on it when I see its busy and release the mutex. The destructor later also release it. Is it okay?